# XML to Text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to convert a xml to text output below. I need to use XSLT for this.
Below is the XML

```
<plan>
    <src>MyDB</src>
    <Id>99999</Id>
    <CollectionA>
        <SubCollection>
            <name>ONE</name>
            <Attributes>
                <Items>1</Items>
                <Items>2</Items>
            </Attributes>
        </SubCollection>
        <SubCollection>
            <name>TWO</name>
            <Attributes>
                <Items>8</Items>
            </Attributes>
        </SubCollection>
        <SubCollection>
            <name>THREE</name>
            <Attributes>
                <Items>0</Items>
                <Items>77</Items>
                <Items>4</Items>
            </Attributes>
        </SubCollection>
    </CollectionA>
</plan>
```

The output text should be in the below format

```
MyDB|99999|ONE|1
MyDB|99999|ONE|2
MyDB|99999|TWO|8
MyDB|99999|THREE|0
MyDB|99999|THREE|77
MyDB|99999|THREE|4
```

Please help! Thanks!!

I've tried with below XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:template match="plan">
  
  <xsl:variable name="header">|<xsl:value-of select="src" />|<xsl:value-of select="Id" /></xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="CollectionA/SubCollection">
 <xsl:variable name="v" select="position()"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat($header, '|', /plan/CollectionA/SubCollection[$v]/name)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output is not expected

```
MyDB|99999|ONE|MyDB|99999|TWO|MyDB|99999|THREE|
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your attempted XSLT script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/plan/CollectionA/SubCollection/Attributes/Items">
      <xsl:value-of select="/plan/src"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="/plan/Id"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../../name"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs:

```
MyDB|99999|ONE|1
MyDB|99999|ONE|2
MyDB|99999|TWO|8
MyDB|99999|THREE|0
MyDB|99999|THREE|77
MyDB|99999|THREE|4
```